# Spring Integration aggregate doesn`t work

Tags: spring, spring-integration

There is my code :
When i do aggregate , my program doesn't give result and doesn`t finish. Do i need to make a custom aggregate logic?(If yes how can i make it)

```
            public boolean accept(Order order){
                log.info("Filter for order: "+order);
                if(order.getOrderState()==(OrderState.CANCELED)){
                    log.info("order " + order + " doesn`t pass filter");
                    return false;
                }
                log.info("order " + order + " pass filter");
                return true;
            }
        
            @Bean
            public IntegrationFlow get() {
                return IntegrationFlows.from("input")
                        .<File, List<String>>transform(this::readFile).<List<String>,List<Order>>transform(this::getOrder)
                        .split().filter(this::accept).aggregate()
                        .get();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a `filter()` in between standard `split()` and `aggregate()`, this is an expected behavior. The splitter produces messages with the correlation details headers: `key`, `sequence` and `size`. Default aggregator relies on those headers to be sure that group is fulfilled, but since some splitted items might be missed because of `false` from the filter, there is no way for default aggregator to build the whole group up to the expected `size`.

This is really possible to fix via something like `groupTimeout()`. Just because we cannot predict how many messages are going to pass the filter, so we only can let it to be released partially after some timeout.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#agg-and-group-to.

On the other hand it looks like you deal with file content. Probably a `FileSplitter` may meet your requirements. It has a `markers` options to emit, so you can be sure to release group when a `FileMarker.END` comes to the aggregator. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-splitter